# Creating handle in a Windows Form with a declared object as an array

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make a Connect 4 game just to practice some windows forms which im new to. What my code does is creates a grid of 7 x 6 regularly spaces blank PictureBox's. But since im creating them in the script and not using the form1 design windows i dont know how i would add Handles to them, especially since the PictureBox's are in an array. Any ideas?

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim Grid(6, 5) As PictureBox
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Visible = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        For i As Integer = 0 To 6
            For j As Integer = 0 To 5
                Grid(i, j) = New PictureBox
                Grid(i, j).BackColor = Color.LightGray
                Grid(i, j).Size = New Size(90, 90)
                Grid(i, j).Location = New Point((i * 100) + 10, (j * 100) + 10)
                Grid(i, j).Visible = True
                Controls.Add(Grid(i, j))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Grid_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Grid(x, y).MouseHover 'Doesnt work
        'Run depending on which picturebox in array 
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can get an error which is "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."

Comment: You must use the AddHandler statement.

Comment: My question, why are you creating them in code in the first place? You know how many there will be and you know where they will be placed so why would you not add them in the designer? There's no point creating new ones over the course of a session because you can just clear the existing ones. It makes no sense to create them in code so you're trying to solve a problem that you created in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way would be to set the `.Tag` property using the coordinates - 
 add something like into your `For..Next` loop

```
Grid(i, j).Tag = i.ToString & j.ToString
```

and use

```
AddHandler Grid(i, j).MouseHover, AddressOf Grid_MouseHover
```

and add this after the one above.

Then, change the first line of your `MouseHover` Sub to

```
Private Sub Grid_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

with no handler on the end.

Finally, change the type of the sender to a `PictureBox`

```
Private Sub Grid_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Pbox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim i As Integer = Integer.Parse(Pbox.Tag.ToString(0))
    Dim j As Integer = Integer.Parse(Pbox.Tag.ToString(1))
End Sub
```

To access the `Picturebox` and its properties, just use `PBox` and if you need the coordinates, use `i` and `j`